# Logo design: is this too simple or boring?

Tags: logo, critique, figure-ground

I'm currently designing a logo for a film production company, but I am struggling a bit and would be grateful some feedback. This is my progress so far:

[image]

I've received some feedback from people on instagram and most seemed to have positive responses but some mentioned the general lack of colour and one said that it is more a badge rather than a logo and is "trying to be an illustration but it is not".

I'm also not sure if what I have done is too safe/obvious and whether I should perhaps come up with something more abstract? Or if it is too simplistic, but then I'm not entirely sure if that's necessarily a bad thing!

One idea which was raised was to go with something completely different and use an icon of a hatchet - as Baltag means hatchet apparently, but I feel that is beyong my logo design abilities.

The company is called 'Victoria Baltag Production', and in terms of design I haven't really been given anything else to go with aside from the name, and that it should convey that it is for a production company.

Comment: "a hatchet job" is slang for something done badly (esp. surgery). I would avoid the image-name association despite the difference in vocational discipline. At some point, a troll might disparage the artwork.

Comment: Did you search the Internet for any other references or associations (visual, cultural, metaphorical, …) for the entity?

Comment: These comments do not qualify as an answer: The line-spacing is irregular. Alignment is non-existent—no two design elements align with each other.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- I recently made a comment on another design, but that also applies in
  this case: avoid designing from our remote memory, on the contrary,
  take as a starting point a real reference and elaborate the
  abstraction. Especially when we are not very good at drawing.
  Is the logo a pictogram of the profile of a film camera?

[image: Film camera]

- You are using a **Gestalt Law**: *[Figure-Ground](https://www.verywellmind.com/what-is-figure-ground-perception-2795195)*. But then you self-sabotage the effect of your design by adding a parallel shadow! It's a nonsense.

> Figure-ground perception refers to the tendency of the visual system to simplify a scene into the main object that we are looking at (the figure) and everything else that forms the background (or ground). The concept of figure-ground perception is often illustrated with the classic "faces or vases" illusion, also known as the Rubin vase. Depending on whether you see the black or the white as the figure, you may see either two faces in profile (meaning you perceive the dark color as the figure) or a vase in the center (meaning you see the white color as the figure).

- How many size reductions the word "PRODUCTION" will support?

[image: reduction]

- There are two relatively unrelated typography families: an Egyptian
  with a humanist sans-serif. This means one with an equal stroke and hard
  rectangular serif with a sans-serif with modulating strokes. As a
  contrast it is valid, but perhaps it should be more accentuated to
  not be interpreted as a graphical mistake.
- Red arrows: three different stroke/serif unions, if the typography is like that, in a two oversize characters playing with figure/ground, brings more confusion than quality to the design.
- Orange arrows: two different stroke/serif unions
- Green arrows: three different gaps between shapes

[image: arrows]

- This is a simple logo with eight shapes, six of them with different
  shape typology, will be good to find a formal meeting point to
  relation them. Shapes 2, 3 and 6 are very *confusing* perceptively.
  In a reduction, shape 2 looks like a mistake.

[image: shapes]

- A positive perceptive point you should enhance: the conjunction
  between V and B gives a point of support in the V and directionality
  in the B, perfect to finish with the camera lens. Don't be shy
  showing it, at the original design the whole lens is nearly hidden or
  worse, together they are a formal wall that stops the dynamics of the
  logo.

[image: directionality]

Comment: I learned a lot about logo design by reading this answer. It is easy to understand, and you outline where the "mistakes" are, and implicitly explain how to fix them.

Comment: @zeethreepio I don't like the edit you made to the answer :-D I accept orthographic rectifications, because I'm not so good in english grammar and orthography, but for the structure i'm sure, actually with your rectification there are some things that loose their sense. There are no titles, just paragraph with bullets. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Fine by me, I think the bullets aren't necessary and they actually muddle up your really great post. I know your rep has skyrocketed in your short time since being on GD.SE, but I'd recommend looking at some of the really good posts and try to match some of the formatting of those. Someone gave me that advice early on and I found it very helpful.

Comment: @John The word you meant to use is explicit—stated clearly. Implicit means not expressed directly.

Comment: A filled "stroke/serif union" is called a filet. A square serif is sometimes referred to as a slab serif. "Human" should be Humanist style.

Comment: Good to know. If there's no filet has a name or is only serif?

Comment: You use the phrase, "Avoid designing from our remote memory…" which I originally did not understand. You use the phrase in another answer, too. Now, I think I understand that what you wish to express by **remote memory** is "**imagination**." Sometimes, you can find "wild (fantasy) imagination" or "vivid (detailed) imagination." When I substitute it, it seems to work. Please check it out and verify that I got it right.

Comment: @Stan Great, sometimes when I don't find the right expression I make the literal Spanish/English translation. I like "vivid imagination". I found this, which is exactly the meaning: https://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/remote+memory

Comment: Remote memory is what I would also call long-term memory. I think I was not correct with my substitute of imagination. It's close but not a valid substitute. Many thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Boring? Depends on who's looking at it. 
If you're referring to color, yes it could be boring and adding some color could bring it to life.

I think it actually looks complicated. If you want to use the initials, dump the camera. Otherwise, dump the initials and use the camera as a main symbol. You are squeezing too much information and its looks squeezed.

Careful however as this is tricky, there must be a zillion companies out there using cameras in their logo or using VB in their logos. At least do some local research and see what other production companies in the same area are doing, so you are not getting too close to their immediate competition.

Also the naming under the *"icon"* is poorly spaced out and misaligned. Work some more on the typesetting.

Answer (score 0):

VB (and also VBP) is already heavily used - it matches with so many possible business names. It's no use to make a new VB. In addition some shark may spot a possiblity to collect money with it. "You have used our design without..."

Name Victoria Baltag is short enough and well memorizable. There's no need to add VB. Of course The V of Victoria could be bigger, but it's also a well used idea, but not totally impossible, if you find a way, how avoid it to be @ictoria, where ictoria is recognized first. An example:

[image]

Whole name including "Production" should be well visible. Let the name be the main subject.

Support the name with minimalistic graphical shape (or nothing like in the V-example) - fully abstract or maybe some production gear derivative, but absolutely unique and ideally easy to coarsely draw manually without flashy software effects. If it is production gear, be sure that it's recognizable. Your current shape is complex and not well recognizable.

Here's an example - again using your texts. The checkmark (=done) resembles letter V, but it's not readable.

[image]

**About color**: It's good, but the basic idea should be fine in black and white. Start from it to be sure.

**About camera**: If a camera must be included, it's a problem. Movie production company cannot use hobby gear, it must at least be something like this guy has:

[image]

That monster is very far from simple. More colors, even one grey, would help to include it.

BTW. Try to avoid using a flapper as V. I think no jokes are wanted here.

Comment: This is much better but why is the V large and styled?

Look at Victoria Secret's logo, it's a logo type, there's no image of an object (except that the V for them might be vagina just as it is for the The View show).

Also, the typeface has thin lines and is deco style ... did you want that? .. or do you want to portray 'science'.  What is being sold ... her eye or her technology?

Comment: @RandyZeitman It actually is not my business to want anything, questioner's client wants. I only showed a few elementary possiblities to the questioner. I used his texts because I have not better idea what the client actually expects.

Comment: Ah. Got it. Good work nonetheless.

Answer (score -7):

The design is redundant.

You are trying to be clever and display an old style movie camera with the two reels as the B and a couple of blocks on the side to imply the lens.

But logos are not descriptors.

Does Apple sell apples? Does Shell sell shells (by the seashore?)

(I can’t name a fortune 1000 company where the logo depipts the product or service.)

The words are explicit.

Make a logotype instead.

Comment: There are a lot of companies whose logos are like the one in the question. How does your answer answer the question being asked?

Comment: No one said there are no companies with a logo like that.

My directly answers the question "but I'm fairly new to logo design, so I am struggling a bit and would be grateful some feedback/pointers." with the answer being 'the graphic element does not need to convey the product or service ... the words already do ... and my evidence for that is that I've yet to see any Fortune 1000 logo (which I am using an arbitrary standard for success)  which is designed to depict the service or product. 

Were you the one that downvoted my reply and then wanted me to explain it after it was judged?

Comment: Logos are not brochures.
They are branding, existential, elements. 
They are meant to be unique and recognizable and as such represent the 'being' (such as 'we are fun', 'we are thinkers', 'we tell stories', etc.), not the 'doing' ('we make see-saws', 'we make electronics', 'we make movies', etc.) of the organization.

https://www.logodesignlove.com/literal-vs-abstract

Comment: –You are trying to be clever...– I think this is not part of a good review. The rest, valid or not, are very subjective personal opinions. It would be redundant if the name were VB Filming Cameras Repair, but that's not the case. It's written just "VICTORIA BALTAG PRODUCTION" that could be VB fashion productions, VB cosmetic productions, VB food productions. Just the camera is telling as the production type. More than redundancy is a good semantic reinforcement.

Comment: Yes, clever can certainly be a very very good thing  but “gimmick“ isn’t really the right word but the only other one I can think of.  Yes, the wording tells the story which you expressed more clearly.   The nature of his inquiry results and every answer being a subjective opinion.  Do you dislike that I offered real world examples clarifying perspective from other designers?   The golden arches are promoting the man and not the product.  You’re welcome to offer counter examples.

Comment: The golden arches are literally french fries. And if we're on the subject of food Burger King's logo is literally a burger.

Comment: hehe!  The golden arches are literally plastic ... an "M" in the fashion of french fries!~